# In Scala, how to write an efficient json formatter for Map[IndexedSeq[String], Int]?

Tags: json, scala, playframework, format, playscalajs

I think there is not a default format for Map[IndexedSeq[String], Int] in scala (right?) So I've written my own format as follows, however it's very slow. Is there a better way to do this?

```
class IndexedSeqToIntMapFormat() extends Format[Map[IndexedSeq[String], Int]] {

 def writes(o: Map[IndexedSeq[String], Int]): JsValue = {
   val mapItems: Seq[String] = o.toSeq.map{case (rowKey, index) => (index.toString +: rowKey).mkString(",")}
   Json.obj("items" -> Json.toJson(mapItems))
 }

 def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Map[IndexedSeq[String], Int]] = {
   val mapItemsAsString: IndexedSeq[String] = (json \ "items").as[IndexedSeq[String]]
   val map: Map[IndexedSeq[String], Int] = mapItemsAsString.map(itemAsString => {
     val item: IndexedSeq[String] = itemAsString.split(",").toIndexedSeq
     val rowKey: IndexedSeq[String] = item.tail
     val rowIndex: Int = item.head.toInt
     (rowKey, rowIndex)
   }).toMap

   JsSuccess(map)
 }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't say for sure whether the following approach is significantly faster than yours, but to my understanding, it does much more conform to the "spirit" of JSON. In a JSON serialization, each object and all its sub-objects and attributes should be named, by what they are. A list of custom string serializations of complex objects is not an actual JSON representation in my opinion.

Doing it in a "proper" JSON way should at least save some time in the parsing, as it does not require additional parsing work on strings but already provides all data in the needed places. *And* the code looks much more readable :-)

The resulting JSON should look like this:

```
"items": [
  { "keySeq": [ "key1", "key2", "key3" ], "value": 42 },
  { "keySeq": [ "key4", "key5" ], "value": 123 },
  { "keySeq": [ "key6", "key7", "key7" ], "value": 650 }
]
```

The formatter could be something like this:

```
class IndexedSeqToIntMapFormat() extends Format[Map[IndexedSeq[String], Int]] {

  def writes(m: Map[IndexedSeq[String], Int]): JsValue = {
    val objs = m.toSeq.map { case (keySeq, value) =>
      Json.obj("keySeq" -> Json.toJson(keySeq), "value" -> JsNumber(value))
    }
    Json.obj("items" -> JsArray(objs))
  }

  def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Map[IndexedSeq[String], Int]] = {
    val seq = (json \ "items").as[Seq[JsValue]] map { obj =>
      ( (obj \ "keySeq").as[IndexedSeq[String]], (obj \ "value").as[Int] )
    }
    JsSuccess(seq.toMap)
  }
}
```

By the way, just out of curiosity - can you tell me in what context you need a such map?

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a try and update this post whether it makes it faster :)

Comment: The running time is just a little faster, but I'm accepting the answer cause I think this is the best we can do.